# Blazor Server Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: "The value 'window.resizeListener' is not a function

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm creating a Blazor Server application and I want to react on the browser resize event with c# code. Therefore I#m following this tutorial: https://jakewaro.medium.com/detecting-browser-resize-in-server-side-blazor-apps-8d75bbab4d37

When I start the application I get this Exception:

```
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: "The value 'window.resizeListener' is not a function.
Error: The value 'window.resizeListener' is not a function.
    at p (http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31071)
    at http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31614
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31587)
    at http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20052
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.invokeClientMethod (http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20022)
    at e.processIncomingData (http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:18006)
    at e.connection.onreceive (http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:11091)
    at WebSocket.i.onmessage (http://localhost:60096/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:39007)"
```

at this command: await JS.InvokeAsync("resizeListener", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));

I'm not sure, why this Method calls window.resizeListener and also this exception only occurs the first time I load the Website. However when I reload the page the code doesn't work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function resizeListener(dotnethelper) {
$(window).resize(() => {
    let browserHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    let browserWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    dotnethelper.invokeMethodAsync('SetBrowserDimensions', browserWidth, browserHeight).then(() => {
        // success, do nothing
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error during browser resize: " + error);
    });
});
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    // Init Browser service with Javascript runtime        
    Browser.Init(JS);
    Browser.Resize += UpdatedBrowserWidth;
}

protected void UpdatedBrowserWidth(object sender, int width)
{
    if (!bigWindowSize && width >= 1000)
    {
        bigWindowSize = true;
        base.StateHasChanged();
    }
    else if (bigWindowSize && width < 1000)
    {
        bigWindowSize = false;
        base.StateHasChanged();
    }
}

public class BrowserService
{
    private IJSRuntime JS = null;
    public event EventHandler<int> Resize;
    private int browserWidth;
    private int browserHeight;
    public async void Init(IJSRuntime js)
    {
        // enforce single invocation            
        if (JS == null)
        {
            this.JS = js;
            await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("resizeListener", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void SetBrowserDimensions(int jsBrowserWidth, int jsBrowserHeight)
    {
        browserWidth = jsBrowserWidth;
        browserHeight = jsBrowserHeight;
        // For simplicity, we're just using the new width
        this.Resize?.Invoke(this, jsBrowserWidth);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use my package, or copy the code from github. https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a long time of trial and error I finally have the solution:

It was to include the JavaScript code directly to the _Hosts file like thi:

```
 <script>
    window.resizeListener = function(dotnethelper) {
        $(window).resize(() => {
            let browserHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
            let browserWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
            dotnethelper.invokeMethodAsync('SetBrowserDimensions', browserWidth, browserHeight).then(() => {
                // success, do nothing
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error during browser resize: " + error);
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

instead of putting int in a seperate .js file, which is only referenced in the _Hosts file.

Also I moved the code from the OnInitialized to Method to the OnRenderAsync Metod (in the if(firstrender))

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong lifecycle method. Blazor server applications do not allow Javascript functions from within any lifecycle method, except for OnAfterRenderAsync. This does not happen in a WebAssembly app since that's loaded on the client. I'm not aware how you render your page though, but I assume you have the option "ServerPrerendered" set, instead of "Server".

The reason this does not happen in your _Host file is because that is always send to the client as a prerendered file, and you obviously don't have any lifecycle methods in a plain cshtml file. To fix this issue, you should execute javascript only after you are certain the page has been rendered.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            // JS code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's true, forgot to mention that on my answer, thank you